# Compare Query Result with CSV/Array and get missing entries

Tags: php, sql, arrays, search, filter

I have a huge CSV File with 20000+ User Entries+User Fields, that i have to compare with our Users in our Database.

The aim is to archive Every User in our database that is not in the CSV File.

My solution would be:

- Get Multidimensional Array out of the CSV File
- Get every User of the Database
- While fetching the User, iterate through CSV array and look if User is in CSV

It is a solution that works but it draws way too much performance.
20,000~ User in CSV * 20,000~ User in Database.
=>400,000,000 Iterations (If no User is found of course...)

Is there a way to reduce the iterations to 20000~?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can import csv data into another table and use SQL join to fetch the desired result. That way your data will be fetch much faster than before. Use temp table to import csv file.